# Change tab title from a spinner in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs, fragment, spinner

I want to change the title of the tab in `OnItemSelected()` method with `String name`.The following is the code for one of the three tabs.

```
package layout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.admin.unitconverter.MainActivity;
import com.example.admin.unitconverter.R;


public class tab_1 extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    Spinner spinner_quantity, spinner_unit;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    public tab_1() {

    }



    public static tab_1 newInstance() {
        tab_1 fragment = new tab_1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);
        spinner_quantity = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1_1);
        spinner_unit = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1_2);
        spinner_quantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = spinner_quantity.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int idSpinner = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "array", tab_1.this.getActivity().getPackageName());

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(idSpinner));
                spinner_unit.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```